# Draw an image in -drawrect or load a same image from a file, which is more efficient?

Tags: graphics, uiview, drawrect

Say I want to display a coordinate graph in UIView which is going to be updated in time. Assume I am implementing `-drawrect` of UIView and other methods to update the graph.

Since the the coordinate frame in the graph stays the same over time, would it be more efficient to have two UIViews, with one (view1) loading the coordinate frame from an image file as its view thus no need to draw the frame every time the graph updates and the other (view2) having `-drawrect` implemented and being added as a subview of view1, than have only one UIView where the entire graph is drawn in `-drawrect`?

Above is just a specific example. What I am wondering is if it's a design pattern to split static UI elements as much as possible from dynamic ones as far as `-drawrect` is involved and if it does substantially save CPU (or GPU) resource in doing so.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that it is often best to have an offscreen buffer where you draw to, and then copy some or all of the offscreen buffer to the screen. There are a number of ways you can do this, and it depends on the type of view you're using. For example, if you have an [NSOpenGLView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you might draw to a texture-backed FBO, and then use that texture to draw a textured quad to the screen. If you are working with CGImages for the static part, you might draw to a CGBitmapContext in main memory, and then turn that bitmap context into a CGImage to draw to the view.

How you draw to your offscreen buffer will also depend on what you're drawing. For something like a graph, you might draw the background once to your offscreen buffer and then add points to a curve you're drawing over it as time progresses, and just copy the portion you need to screen. For something like a game where all the characters and objects in the scene are moving, you might need to draw everything in the scene on every frame.

Comment: Thank for the reply. Well, I am totally new in programming, especially in graphics. I know what buffer is but have no idea about 'offscreen buffer', texture-backed FBO. From what I understood vaguely from your answers it's that it confirms my idea that I should draw static graphical contents as few times as possible (of course not for games where static contents are rare) and copy these contents from memory to screen. Thus separating dynamic and static content in code is encouraged. Was I understanding you correctly?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that can be a winning strategy in many cases, but that you need to tailor your approach to your specific needs. It sounds like in this case it would be a win for you.